# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported write variant! at javax.imageio.ImageWriter.unsupported(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I have been trying to programatically create one png file from a number of other png files in Java using javax.imageio.

In particular I have been trying to use the answer outlined in [How do I convert multiple png images to a single tiff file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792255/how-do-i-convert-multiple-png-images-to-a-single-tiff-file/793857#793857)

However when I call the `writeInsert(..)` method I keep getting the below Exception.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported write variant!
at javax.imageio.ImageWriter.unsupported(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageWriter.writeInsert(Unknown Source)
```

I understand that the `canInsertImage` returns whether it is possible to insert or not (and I can see that this method returns false) however I do not know how to change this.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;

public class ImageTest
{

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ImageOutputStream ios = null;
    ImageWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        String dirName = "C:/png/test";
        File dir = new File(dirName);
        if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory())
        {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            if (null != files && files.length > 0)
            {
                File outFile = new File("C:/png", "output.png");

                ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outFile);

                Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("png");
                if (null != writers && writers.hasNext())
                {

                    writer = writers.next();
                    writer.setOutput(ios);
                    ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

                    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
                    {
                        InputStream fis = null;
                        try
                        {
                            fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(files[i]));
                            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fis);
                            IIOImage img = new IIOImage(image, null, null);

                            if (i == 0)
                            {
                                writer.write(null, img, param);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                writer.writeInsert(-1, img, param);
                            }
                            image.flush();
                        } finally
                        {
                            if (null != fis)
                            {
                                fis.close();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("OOOps: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally
    {
        if (null != ios)
        {
            ios.close();
        }
        if (null != writer)
        {
            writer.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: A PNG file does **not** hold multiple images. The TIFF format can do that, but the PNG format can't. That's not a software restriction (i.e. changing your code or switching to another library won't help). That's a format restriction.

Comment: Cheers Joachim.
I found another (simpler) method outlined in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922276/how-to-combine-multiple-pngs-into-one-big-png-file .
A slight adjustment and I had what I needed